# import tables to generate thousands of new rows in a new one

Tags: sql-server, random, import, concatenation

I need to populate a table with names(first name and surname).

This tables are in xlsx. I need to import and then concatenate the names. I want a code that generate random 100 names but if i want it can generate thousands.

helpp

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post what you've tried and we'd be glad to help.  We're not going to write it for you, though.

Comment: I've imported the xlsx with import wizard and tried to create index for those 2 tables 

CREATE INDEX NomePerfil
ON perfis (#Nomesproprios, #Surname)

but this didn't work.. 
And i dont know how to create random row with those two tables

Answer (score 0):

Import data from Excel to sql server using the Import and Export wizard.

**[`Read more about SQL Server Import and Export wizard here.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189667.aspx)**

Then, concatenate first name and surname columns using `+` operator. Then use `TOP n` to select n number of rows.

**Query**

```
select distinct top 100 [firstname] + ' ' + [surname]
from [your_table_name];
```

Comment: that works but only concatenates the first row of each table to a new name..
i want a row that selects random rows of those tables
thanks a lot!